# How to correctly use braces or gsl::narrow_cast in MFC project?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, code-analysis

I have seen this discussed on here from my research but I am still encountering issues and not sure.

My code:

```
m_gridAssignHist.SetRowCount(static_cast<int>(mapHistory.size()) + 1);
```

The code analysys is saying to either use braces or `gsl::narrow_cast`:

```
m_gridAssignHist.SetRowCount(gsl::narrow_cast<int>(mapHistory.size()) + 1);
```

- I am not sure how to correctly use braces in this context and would appreciate clarification.
- My IDE is flagging `gsl::` as unknown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of suggestion by code analysis is to check narrowing conversion

`int{value}` is narrowing conversion that can be checked in *compile-time*, if `value` is constant. `int{mapHistory.size()}` should not compile.

`gsl` check is *runtime*, so it will actually check the value range in your case. To make it compiling, [obtain gsl library](https://github.com/microsoft/GSL), and make it available to the compiler.